# Solving simple quotes and Php

Tags: php, html, quotes, quote, addslashes

Sorry if that question has been already answered but what i found on the internet didn't help me that much.I got a problem with php and simple quotes

Here is my code :

```
echo "<span onclick='search(\"".$value."\");'>".some stuff."</span>";
```

My problem is that $value is sometimes with simple quotes (they are music titles). So i got some problems with 't' stands for trouble, can't stand losing you ...

I tryed with `addslashes($value)` but it does not work.
Any idea ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with `htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES);`

it's better also to get rid of all these slashes:

```
?>
<span onclick='search("<?=htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES);?>");'>
    some stuff
</span>
<?php
// back to php
```

Comment: You're right, i should use this more often than the echo method we learn at school ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can HTML encode ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php ), it will make HTML entities out of the special characters in your titles. Be sure to decode on the recieving end though.

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace("'", "&#39;", $value);
```

should change quotes to their XML entity...

Answer (score 0):

You may use htmlentities function:

```
echo "<span onclick='search(\"".htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES)."\");'>".some stuff."</span>";
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, i tried with htmlentities($value) and it didn't work, with the code given by Eugene (htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES)) it worked !! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

your proper syntax should be something like this. Use [htmlentites($value,ENT_QUOTES)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to handle the special characters

```
$sanitizedValue  = htmlentites($value,ENT_QUOTES);

echo "<span onclick='search(\"{$sanitizedValue}\");'>some stuff</span>";
```